# Work with table named Group

Tags: sql-server, select, table

I have a table named Group in my database , when I try to work on it it gave error :

```
 SELECT GroupID,GroupName FROM Group
```

it said :

```
     Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
     Incorrect syntax near 'Group'.
```

I know that Group is illegal name for table but its a old database with too many data and relations , and I cant rename this table , is there any way to work with table ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add brackets with table, as `Group` is a reserved word for `Group by` clause in SQL Server.

```
SELECT GroupID,
GroupName 
FROM [dbo].[Group]
```